# Synonyms and Stop-words in Solr

Tags: solr, stop-words, synonym

I am on Solr 7.4. I have two fields in my schema ("title_en" and "body_en") that are of the delivered field type `"text_en"`, which is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I have a synonyms file which has the following definition

```
 usa,united states of america
```

If I search a query term "USA" or "United States of America" using the EDisMax query parser, then I see the following:

```
"parsedquery":"+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((body_en:usa) | (title_en:usa)))"
```

It seems as if the synonyms are being ignored if they include a stop-word (in this case ‘of’ in the synonym ‘united states of america’).

I would have expected something like this:

```
parsedquery":"+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((((+body_en:unit +body_en:state +body_en:america) body_en:usa))
 | (((+title_en:unit +title_en:state +title_en:america) title_en:usa))))
```

Is there some conflict I'm running into between Stop-words and Synonyms - perhaps based on the order of query parsing operations? Any suggestions as to how to overcome this?

Comment: You can use the Analysis Screen (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/analysis-screen.html) to validate the synonyms are indeed being applied (here is an example https://library.brown.edu/DigitalTechnologies/using-synonyms-in-solr/) Also, did you restart Solr after updating the synonyms file? Does it work with synonyms that don't have a stop word?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Hector. The Analysis page has always shown the successful application of the synonyms (with or without stopwords).It is when using the Dismax or eDisMax options where I see the synonyms not getting applied correctly